# How to put\save files into some public directory? (adobe air)

Tags: actionscript-3, file, filesystems, air, share

We develope for multy users OS. So my Air App needs to save some files to let all users acsess them (and be able to acsess them on its own). So I need a function to save files into public directoris (crossplatform function) .

Can any one please share such one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4c56-7fc1) has the examples you need.